# Chrome: Salesforce Lightning Setup pages opens as new tab

Tags: lightning-experience, chrome

Lately when I work on Chrome in Lightning Experience I noticed a strange behaviour. When I try to open a Setup page it always opens the actual page as a new tab. Also making it non functional anymore. When I open it in a incognito browser it works fine. So in short, it opens the "Classic" setup pages in a new tab for some reason.

Anyone else is having the same or has a solution?

Comment: Your title says "Lightning", but your question asks about "Classic". Which Setup are you actually trying to use when it opens in a new tab and from which kind of session, Lightning or Classic?

Comment: Resolved. My plugin Ghostery was blocking the iframe 'Classic' setup pages. I've marked the Salesforce pages as Trusted and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved. My plugin Ghostery was blocking the iframe 'Classic' setup pages. I've marked the Salesforce pages as Trusted and that resolved the issue.